# how to highlight a bar in stacked bar chart d3.js v4

Tags: d3.js

I want to highlight a bar with April (value in x-axis) with a square box. but I am not getting a approach to do the same.

tried getting the co-ordinates of the respected bar, but unable to find a solution for the same

Unable to find the co-ordinates of the respective bar which I need to highlight.

what should be the approach for highlighting a bar with a square box in stacked bar chart d3.js v4

```js
createStackedBarChart(130,300,10,60,20,45,"manager-line-graph-2");

function createStackedBarChart(height,width,top,right,bottom,left,id){

    var margin = {top: top, right: right, bottom: bottom, left: left };
    //console.log("margin"+margin);
    var svg = d3.select("#"+id).append("svg"),      
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.2)
    .align(5.0);
  

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#0000FF", "#00FFFF", "#81F781", "#F3F781", "#FE2E2E"]);

 var data = [
  {"Months": "Feb","Installation": 5,"Product": 10,"Payment": 15,"Billing": 20,"Outage": 25},
  {"Months": "March","Installation": 6,"Product": 8,"Payment": 9,"Billing": 15,"Outage": 18},
  {"Months": "April","Installation": 9,"Product": 12,"Payment": 24,"Billing": 17,"Outage": 14},
  {"Months": "May","Installation": 9,"Product": 12,"Payment": 14,"Billing": 17,"Outage": 14},
  {"Months": "June","Installation": 9,"Product": 12,"Payment": 15,"Billing": 11,"Outage": 10}
];
  // fix pre-processing
  var keys = [];
  for (key in data[0]){
    if (key != "Months")
      keys.push(key);
  }

  console.log("value of keys are " + keys);

  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.total = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(k){
      d.total += d[k];
    })
  });

  //data.sort(function(a, b) {
    //return b.total - a.total;
  //});
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Months;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.total;
  })]).nice();
  z.domain(keys);

  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {return z(d.key);})
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.data.Months);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth()-5);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5, "s"))
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("y", y(y.ticks(5).pop()))
    .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start") 

  var legend = g.append("g")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
    });
  
  
    //legend.append("rect")
    //.attr("x", width + 20)
    //.attr("width", 10)
    //.attr("height", 10)
    //.attr("fill", z);

    legend.append("circle")
    .attr("r",5)
    .attr("cx", width+30)      
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("fill",z);

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width + 88)
    .attr("y", 3.5)
    .attr("dy", "0.12em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return`enter code here` d;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have used previously is to create an invisible layer of bars for the same data. Then use the `.on("mouseover", function...);` to make the bars for that data visible again by changing the styles or the fill opacity.

Here is a sample bl.ock with what I mean. It is a grouped bar chart with ordinal scale, but the same could be applied to your data with some tweaking. 
https://bl.ocks.org/Coola85/b05339b65a7f9b082ca210d307a3e469

Update May 5, 2018: upon further reading I see your issue is different than the solution I suggested. This link might give you a good starting point of how to [use an if statement to selectively highlight particular data](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/select-items-with-if-statement-in-d3js.html).

so you could use the following style for your rect

```
.style ("fill", function(d) {
   if (d.Months === "April") {return "red"}  // <== Add these
   else    { return "black" } 
  })
```

Comment: Could not get you ?   can you please make the code change on the above or tell me what code I need to make.

Comment: Updated answer with an example bl.ock please check. If this is something you would like.

Comment: Hi Rahul. Upon further reading I see the solution I provided may be different than what you desire. Could you please create a bl.ock in blockbuilder or a plunk in plunker with some sample data.